# Runtime error in Armstrong number program

Tags: visual-c++

Problem-To print Armstrong number between any two numbers

Error-Wrong output

Compiled in VS code

I am a beginner in C++. I was creating an armstrong number program to identify numbers between any two range. However, code stops compiling after printing "100" which is also a wrong output. Here is my code to get reviewed.

```
{int num1,num2,a,rem,result=0,n=0;
cout<<"Enter first number: ";
cin>>num1;
cout<<"Enter second number: ";
cin>>num2;
cout<<"Armstrong numbers between "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" are: "<<endl;
while (num1 != num2) //looping till first and last number becomes equal
{
    //incrementing 'n' value to the number of digits in entered number  
    a=num1;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        a/=10;
        n++;    
    }
    a=num1; //redefining a value to num1
    while (a != 0) //looping to generate result
    {
        rem=a%10;
        result+=pow(rem,n);
        a/=10;
    }
    if (result==num1)
    {
        cout<<result<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    n=0;
    num1++;
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: You don't reset `result` between loop iterations. It keeps accumulating the sum across all numbers tested.

Answer (score 0):

Remove else code, it is looping current number infinitely

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, a, rem, result = 0, n = 0;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter second number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Armstrong numbers between " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " are: " << endl;
    while (num1 != num2) //looping till first and last number becomes equal
    {
        //incrementing 'n' value to the number of digits in entered number
        a = num1;
        while (a != 0)
        {
            a /= 10;
            n++;
        }
        a = num1;      //redefining a value to num1
        while (a != 0) //looping to generate result
        {
            rem = a % 10;
            result += pow(rem, n);
            a /= 10;
        }
        if (result == num1)
        {
            cout << result << endl;
        }

        // you do not have to use else here. 
        // It will automatically continue with next line
        n = 0;
        a = 0;
        result = 0;
        num1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```